# In the hibernate.cfg.xml file, can you use both mapping resource, and mapping class in the same session factory?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I'm making putting together a system that does the basic job of persisting hibernate POJOs into a database.  We've got a bit of a legacy system in place at the moment where the older POJOs are generated by hbm.xml files, but the new POJOs are just annotated classes.

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <!-- Database connection settings HSQL DB -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password" />
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="show_comments">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</property>
        <mapping resource="com/dto/Address.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="com.dto.Customer"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is ok except when it comes time to Unit testing and it appears that having both a resource and a class mapping in the cfg.xml file seems to break unit tests at build time.

```
    <mapping resource="com/dto/Address.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="com.dto.Customer"/>
```

Is there a way round this?  Can I even use the 2 differnt mapping types in a hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: According to the Hibernate documentation, you can mix annotated persistent classes and classic hbm.cfg.xml declarations with the same SessionFactory. You can however not declare a class several times (whether annotated or through hbm.xml). You cannot mix configuration strategies (hbm vs annotations) in an entity hierarchy either.

Comment: Ah well... I'll just have to convert the classes generated by the hbm.xml files into annotated classes(my preferred way of doing things hibernate-wise).  Thank you for your help!